# PhpStorm terminal : Cygwin colors does not work

Tags: terminal, cygwin, wamp, phpstorm, symfony-console

I have PhpStorm 2016.2 and I added Cygwin in the Shell path as follow : `"C:\cygwin64\bin\env.exe" CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash.exe`

It's working well, but the colors do not work.
For exemple I have `?[32m Name` instead of having `Name` colored in green.

I tried several things like adding the plugin Grep Console to have the support of ANSI Color, but didn't work.

It's really hard to work with lines with multiple ANSI colors `?[39m ?[32m Scheme ?[39m ?[32m Host ?[39m ?[32m Path`.

Do not hesitate to ask further information about the problem. Thank you.

P.S. I'm on Windows 10.

**EDIT**

when I do `/usr/bin/which php` in PHPStorm terminal I get `/cygdrive/d/wamp2/bin/php/php5.6.16/php`. I have php5.6.16 and php7.0.0 in my WAMP and I'm currently using php7.0.0.

**EDIT 2** I added a $PATH for php7.0.0 so now I have `/cygdrive/d/wamp2/bin/php/php7.0.0/php` when I do `/usr/bin/which php`. But the main problem remains.

Comment: Terminal supports ANSI colors in general (works fine for me here on Windows 7 (using `cmd`) if I execute command like `npm.cmd outdated -g` (which has colourful output)). It could be that Cygwin/bash has something to do here...

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
When I do `php bin/console d:r` in Phpstorm terminal with Cygwin env.exe I get the ANSI color code `?[32m`.
But when I do the same command directly in Cygwin I get the good color display.
So my Cygwin looks ok. It's more like Phpstorm is badly interpreting the things that the command gives back.

Comment: I just tested something interesting.

When I do `ls -l --color=always` in my Phpstorm terminal with Cygwin I get the colors. It seems that only symfony commands (e.g : `php bin/console d:r`) gives ANSI code `?[32m`. But I still don't know where the bugs comes from...

Comment: Please provide the build of Windows 10 you are using. `(Click Windows Icon -> Settings -> System -> About)` there are issues with `version 1607/build 14393` (Anniversary Update) which seems to be causing some issues with ANSI console support.

Comment: @fyrye My windows 10 : version 1511 / 10586.494. I checked windows update, it tells me that I can update my windows to Windows 10, version 1607. I think I shouldn't do thet update no ?

Comment: @WillMic it's a decent update, but will cause the same issue you're experiencing in the Windows Command Line Terminal and other Emulators, without a current resolution. A benefit is that it does come with Linux Bash (Ubuntu-Based Bash for Windows), which you can use for your PHP installation, etc and is not affected by the same Terminal Emulation issues.

Comment: @WillMic You may need to install `php-posix`extension in your Cygwin PHP environment. Aside from that Cygwin should come with MinTTY which provides color (ANSI) support. Symfony should colorize when the `ANSICON` environment variable is defined (check `~/.bash_rc`) for it. Only other suggestion is to pass the `--no-ansi` flag like so `php bin/console --no-ansi your-command` or `php composer.phar --no-ansi your-command` to disable color output.

Comment: @fyrye Sorry but I don't really know how to do what you're suggesting. Could you please give more details about it.

Answer (score 7):

Adding second answer to provide an alternative solution to my original answer.

**ANSICON Support**

First download and install [ANSICON](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases)

- Extract the windows binary files 
  *(x86 or x64 directory contents)* into your `$PATH` (`D:\wamp\bin\php\php7.0.0`)
- Optionally run `ansicon -i` from a Windows Command Prompt
  to allow you to use `ANSICON` to add ansi color support to the Windows Command Prompt.

Next you need to wrap `ANSICON` for the PHPStorm terminal

```
"X:\path\to\ansicon.exe" -p "C:\cygwin64\bin\env.exe" CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash.exe
```

[image: Ansicon Wrapper]

> *NOTE:* Using `-l` or `--login`, as stated in the original answer, will add `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH` and cause the
>   terminal to use the Cygwin PHP installation making ANSICON unneeded.

Next in your `~/.bashrc` file you will need to add at the bottom of the file.

```
export ANSICON=true
```

You can easily append the line by running the following command from a Cygwin terminal.

```
echo export ANSICON=true >> ~/.bashrc
```

This will ensure Symfony will find the ANSICON environment variable with a different Windows Version.

Next restart PHPStorm and open the terminal to test it out.
[image: Composer Ansicon]

Comment: As a side note there does appear to be a PHP Bug regarding the issue: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72768

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! In PHPStorm terminal, when I type `php bin/console d:r` I get the colors. But now there's a new bug when I type commands like `composer self-update` or use a gulp : `$ composer self-update` `/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bi‌​n/composer: line 3: dirname: command not found` `/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bi‌​n/composer: line 17: sed: command not found` `Could not open input file: /composer.phar`. And the second bug I get is that, after one or two entered command in the terminal, I can't type in anymore, I have to open a new terminal tab to do so.

Comment: @WillMic The PHPStorm terminal is screwy, sometimes if you get to the bottom it doesn't always refresh, so you have to drag the top bar, resizing the height, in order to get it to detect the terminal's inner height. As for `dirname: command not found` I suggest adding `export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to the bottom of your `~/.bashrc` file to ensure your Terminal environment includes it. Otherwise add the `--login` switch in my original answer to load up the full Cygwin environment (.bash_profile).

Comment: No, I know it can get screwy but that's not it. Opening a new tab and keep a key pressed and after a random number of caracters (5~40) it stops typing. Sometimes I copy paste and can't press enter. There's a real problem in the PHPStorm terminal since I used the last shell path. And for the other thing. I typed `echo export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc` in my Cygwin console and I think I did it wrong... I get the error message at the top of any Cygwin console (PHPStorm too) `-bash: /home/USER/.bashrc: line 200: syntax error near unexpected token « ( »`

Comment: Manually navigate to it and edit it, `C:\cygwin64\home\<username>\.bashrc` for example: `"C:\cygwin64\home\fyrye\.bashrc"` Remove the messed up line on 200 and add it manually.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue of the [PHPStorm terminal](http://imgur.com/Q4OFKWV) input becoming unresponsive. Since you're using x64 Cygwin, ensure you are using the x64 executable of PHPStorm. Also ensure you are using the x64 version of the ANSICON binaries.

Comment: @WillMic What is the purpose of Cygwin if not for the LAMP stack it provides?

Comment: Thanks it's ok about this. But I still have the terminal blocked after some time (random). The cursor is flashing so I guess the terminal didn't crashed but I still can't make it work. Always have to open a tab to make it works again for a little moment : not really convenient. Do you think there's a problem with my shell path ? `"D:\wamp2\bin\php\php7.0.0\ansicon.exe" -p "C:\cygwin64\bin\env.exe" CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash.exe`

Comment: I use PhpStorm64.exe and I copied the x64 folder from ansi166. And to answer your question : I often have to use unix commands or others that are in Cygwin and not in default cmd.exe so to keep everything in PhpStorm I want to get Cygwin to work in it.

Comment: But if it bother you, don't spend too much time on it. I can stop using this and deal with it.

Comment: Found your issue, simply add `--login` to your terminal path of PHPStorm, as in my original answer. Not sure why composer would complain that `dirname` didn't exist, since it is contained within PHP, but in order to run Windows commands within the Cygwin environment it has to load the full environment. It is a `$PATH` related issue since `which dirname` return `/usr/bin/dirname` Not sure about the terminal locking up though, since I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Oh, actualy I already had --login in it. So I removed it, and now the terminal works almost perfect. Now I can type as much as I want. I can navigate in folders. But it stops working when I do command like `ls -l` or when I launch `gulp`, or with `php bin/console d:r`. I still have the cursor flashing though, but nothing else. Almost there Haha !

Comment: If you added `/usr/bin` to your `$PATH` that would resolve the issue you were having with `command not found`. For the terminal locking up, make sure you're using the correct x64 JRE for the PHPStorm version you're using and uninstall all others. I use JDK x64 1.8.0_60.

Comment: I don't have any more problem with `command not found` : it's ok for this. And for PHPStorm I use those two variable : `JAVA_HOME` `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101` and `JDK_HOME` `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92`. I am using PHPStorm64. Is this ok ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `-l` switch to your terminal path.

Before adding the switch:
[image: Cygwin Before Switch]

The full path should be

```
"C:\cygwin64\bin\env.exe" CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash.exe -l
```

or

```
"C:\cygwin64\bin\env.exe" CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/bash.exe --login
```

[image: PHPStorm Cygwin Terminal]

Be sure to close the currently opened terminal window **by clicking the red X** in the upper left of the terminal dialog and reopen it.
[image: Close Terminal]

Now running the command again it should look like:
[image: Cygwin After Switch]

See `man bash` within the Cygwin terminal for more information.

---

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment about your WAMP installation. You'll need to install PHP in Cygwin for it to run correctly, which will allow the use of the `posix` line of functions and emulate a Linux distribution for your PHP environment. Which is generally why Cygwin is used.

How are you intending to use Cygwin with PHP?

The issue is that Cygwin is using the Windows PHP executable and the Symfony Console Component `StreamOutput` is detecting it as a Windows instance of PHP and and not Cygwin/Linux in order to use `posix_isatty`.

Here is an example of the code Symfony Console uses to render color output to the terminal.

```
if ('\\' === DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) {
    static::$defaultColors = @(
        0 >= version_compare('10.0.10586', PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_MAJOR.'.'.PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_MINOR.'.'.PHP_WINDOWS_VERSION_BUILD)
        || false !== getenv('ANSICON')
        || 'ON' === getenv('ConEmuANSI')
        || 'xterm' === getenv('TERM')
    );
} elseif (function_exists('posix_isatty')) {
    $h = stream_get_meta_data($this->outputStream) + array('wrapper_type' => null);
    $h = 'Output' === $h['stream_type'] && 'PHP' === $h['wrapper_type'] ? fopen('php://stdout', 'wb') : $this->outputStream;
}
```

Comment: I tried both of those path and none of them worked : I still have `?[39m ?[32m` in my PhpStorm 2016.2 terminal. Is this normal ?

Comment: No it's not normal as Symfony detects support and may mean that your cygwin profile is altered. Launch the terminal in PHPStorm and run this line. `php -r 'var_dump(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == "\\");'` It should return `false` when the cygwin environment is initializing correctly, instead of `true`. If it is `false` run `php -r "var_dump(function_exists('posix_isatty'));"` which should return `true`. Also ensure you update `composer.phar` `php composer.phar self-update` from the terminal. As a note I am also using PhpStorm 2016.2.

Comment: Additionally you can check `echo $PATH` to ensure the `/usr/bin` and `/usr/local/bin` are **prefixed** to all other environment paths. Lastly you should ensure MinTTY is available in your Cygwin environment in `/usr/bin/mintty.exe` or install it by running the cygwin setup and searching for [MinTTY](http://imgur.com/gx1qAkT)

Comment: Also be sure you're closing the terminal (or PHPStorm) completely and not just hiding it, so that it re-instantiates the terminal. Updated my answer with images  to illustrate the steps I took.

Comment: @WillMic Lastly please update your question with the output of `/usr/bin/which php` from the PHPStorm terminal. I am thinking there may be a path conflict and the wrong PHP executable is running, such as from an XAMP or WAMP installation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. So to sum up I tried everything you said and it still does not work. But there are some reason. When I did `php -r 'var_dump(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR == "\\");'` it returned `bool(true)`. And `php -r "var_dump(function_exists('posix_isatty'));"` returned `false`. So there's a problem here. I did a `composer self-update` and at least this worked ^^

Comment: I don't know why but I can't edit my question.... So when I do `/usr/bin/which php` in PHPStorm terminal I get `/cygdrive/d/wamp2/bin/php/php5.6.16/php`. I have php5.6.16 and php7.0.0 in my WAMP and I'm currently using php7.0.0.

Comment: Updated my answer with my result. Effectively the issue is caused by calling the WAMP PHP executable within Cygwin. I was unsuccessful in bridging windows based ANSI support to Cygwin using ANSICON or other libraries. Though I am very curious on how you're intending to use Cygwin if you are using a WAMP installation of PHP.

Comment: @WillMic I got it working and added a second answer.