# ANSI color codes in PhpStorm console

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

Can anyone tell me how to turn on ANSI color codes in PhpStorm terminal? For now, I've got this view:

[image]

About console type, I've tested Git sh.exe and Cygwin. Colors were visible on `cmd.exe` but I needed "better" console.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After loooooong hours, I managed to make it work right.

For the first step, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39022933/912130) in StackOverflow. Thanks to this topic, I learned about [adoxa/ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases) for ANSICON support. I downloaded it and unpacked on my desktop.

Next thing - found better terminal - [Babun](https://babun.github.io/) in this case. After installation, I've read [THIS](http://engineroom.teamwork.com/using-cygwins-bash-terminal-in-a-jetbrains-ide/) article. It told me to change the Shell path in PhpStorm to:

```
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\.babun\cygwin\bin\bash.exe
```

Above that, I added `cd $OLDPWD` to the end of

```
C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\.babun\cygwin\etc\bash.bashrc
```

file to open my PhpStotm terminal in the project directory.

After everything, I changed my Shell path in PhpStorm again, to:

```
"C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\Desktop\ansi166\x64\ansicon.exe" -p C:\Users\YOUR-USERNAME\.babun\cygwin\bin\bash.exe
```

And all is working properly now :).

Answer (score 2):

For those who do not want to change terminal and continue with the windows prompt, just download and unzip [adoxa/ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/releases) and change the shell path in PhpStorm to `"YOUR-FOLDER-UNZIP-ANSICON\x64\ansicon.exe" -p cmd.exe`